# RavenDB ForEach ExtensionMethod abstraction

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I am doing a lot of backend data manipulation of data in RavenDb (not website crud). I have dozens of methods scattered around for doing essentially the same skip/take queries, but with different parameters. Much of what I want is simply: foreach document in the db that matches this query, do this action.

I created a little helper, but can't seem to figure out how to apply a selector to it. For instance, my end goal might be to write:

```
MyDocStore.ForEach<Users>( 
     x => x.Where(u => u.LastName == "Smith").OrderBy( u => u.FirstName), 
     x => Console.WriteLine( "{0}", x.FirstName),
     take: 12);
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static class RavenHelper
{
    public static void ForEach<TSource>(
         this IDocumentStore documentStore, 
          Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TSource>> selector, 
          Action<TSource> action, 
          int take = 128)
    {
        var skip = 0;
        while( true )
        {
            using( var session = documentStore.OpenSession() )
            {
                var list = session.Query<TSource>();
                // How do I apply more selectors? 
                var result = list.Take( take ).Skip( skip ).ToList();

                if( !result.Any() )
                {
                    return;
                }

                foreach( var il in result )
                {
                    action(il);
                }

                skip += take;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So your `selector` parameter may be various extention calls chained together? Or will you hava Where and Sort only?

Comment: I would love to be anything that makes sense in a typical linq call. For instance, the .Customize() call is used for RavenDb often.

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
      Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> selector,
```

And then call:

```
       .Where(selector)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this only handles a single expression. I don't see how a chain could happen (doing both a where and orderby (see the original question)).